# How can I transform an variable, or the record, into an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a record in the MySQL database that was saved this way

```
{"pt" => "Promoção de Férias","en" => "Vacation Promotion"}
```

I get this record in the bank and put it in a variable

```
$retornoBanco= '{"pt" => "Promoção de Férias","en" => "Vacation Promotion"}';
```

How can I transform this variable, or the record, into an array

```
$arr= ??????
```

Comment: That looks like a mix'n'mash between json and php-array-syntax. You need to parse it yourself. The people that gives you that string might be able to tell you if that is some specific data format.

Comment: 1/ Try to get a valid JSON format so you just have to use `json_decode` or 2/ The ugly way : remove the `{` and `}` with php then `explode()` the string by `,` and do a `foreach` to build your array with other `explode()` by `=>`...but it's will be very case sensitive and a little change will make the code impossible to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert the string into JSON format using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function, by replacing `=>` with `:` (your string is mix of PHP array and JSON format).
- Then, you can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function with second parameter set to true, to get an associative array.

Try ([**Rextester DEMO**](https://rextester.com/KAUX53387)):

```
$retornoBanco= '{"pt" => "Promoção de Férias","en" => "Vacation Promotion"}';

// converting to JSON format
$retornoBanco = str_replace('=>', ':', $retornoBanco);

// converting to array
$retornoBanco_array = json_decode($retornoBanco, true);
```